# Graph API returns invalid userIds of public group members

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, userid

I'm requesting data of a public Facebook group. Including feed, comments, reactions etc.

The problem is, that some of the userIds of likes, posts or comments are invalid.

Can anyone help me to figure out why I get invalid ids?

Thank you,
Christine

Comment: What do you mean with invalid?

Comment: When I'm looking for the users profile by url (http://www.facebook.com/{useId}) Facebook redirects to a page which says that the userId does not exist. I know that the app-scoped user-id is not the "real" userId. But it actually redirects to the users profile.

Comment: There is a link property on the user object that gets you the link to the user